# Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message already in use

Tags: java, swing, loops, derby

I am using derby database in a swing application. The query is as follows:

```
private String LEDGERGROUP(long Name){
String LG= "";
try{
String query = "SELECT LEDGER_GROUP FROM LEDGER_MASTER WHERE LEDGER_CODE = "+Name+" ";         
conn= con.db();
stmtt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
rs = stmtt.executeQuery(query);
if(rs.next()){
LG = rs.getString("LEDGER_GROUP")  ;
}}
catch (SQLException ex ) {
//JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unknown Error!!"+ex);
System.out.println("Unknown Error!!"+ex);
} finally{try{if(stmtt!=null){stmtt.close();} if(conn!=null){conn.close();} if(rs!=null){rs.close();}}catch(SQLException ex){}}

return LG;

}
```

I am calling this message to update a jtable with a loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i<jTable1.getRowCount(); i++){
String code = jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
Long l = Long.parseLong(code);
String lc = LEDGERGROUP(l);
jTable1.setValueAt(lc, i, 2);
}
```

The loop runs fine for a while. But suddenly I get the error message. `Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message already in use.` Why this message? How can I get rid of this message and continue with the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message already in use.
```

Exception came when any other process using your port `1527` check which process using that port and kill that process.

Comment: How can I do it through my java program ?